# Python matrix comparison

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix, comparison

I have big data like:

```
{'a_1':0b110000,
 'a_2':0b001100,
 'a_3':0b000011,
 'b_1':0b100100,
 'b_2':0b000001,
 'c_1':0b100000,}
```

and so on... the structure of the data can be reorganized and is more to show, what I want to achieve. Rows of 'a' will never overlap by their sub-rows.
What would be a performant way, to get the best combinations of two (ab,ac) or three (abc) or more rows in terms of most matching values?
Hope, the questions is clear somehow, hard to describe :/
Maybe some matrix operations of numpy?

more info:
possible combinations of two would be ab,ac,bc. ab would check rows of a (a_1,a_2,a_3) against rows of b (b_1,b_2) each other. a_1 & b_1 means 0b110000 & 0b100100 and would give one result. a_1 & b_2 means 0b110000 & 0b000001 and would give no result. That would be the description of a solution by loops, but it is very slow, especially with combinations of 8 or so (not covered by example data).

maybe a more clear structure of the data:

```
{'a': [0b110000,
       0b001100,
       0b000011],
 'b': [0b100100,
       0b000001],
 'c': [0b100000]}
```

Let me show, how I'm doing those calculations until now. The data-structure is kind of different, as I tried to start this question with an 'I thought' better structure...

```
data = {'a':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'b':[4,5,5,5,4,5],
        'c':[6,7,7,7,6,7]}    

combine_count = 3
for config in combinations(['a','b','c'],combine_count):
    ret = {}
    for index,combined in enumerate(zip(*tuple(data.get(k) for k in config))):
        ret.setdefault(combined, []).append(index)

for k,v in ret.items():
    score = len(v)
    if score >= 2:
        print(k,score)
```

my problem with this is, that especially the process of constructing combined with larger combine_count takes a lot of time.
data of course is a lot larger. It has about 231 keys with lists each of length ~60000. Also, the RAM consumption is too high.

Comment: use the data example to show exactly what result you achieve. (ab,ac) and (abc) seem to have appeared from nowhere and don't relate to your big data very directly.

Comment: added some more infomation. Hope, that helps.

Comment: so would ab result in a1&b1->16,a1&b2->0,a2&b1->4,a2&b2->0,a3&b1->0,a3&b2->1 which would all score 1 match and be equal? For your triple version would the valuation be, say, a1&b1 | a1&c1 | b1&c1 ?

Comment: exactly. more matching ones means higher score. but the triple evaluation would be a1&b1&c1 | a2&b1&c1 ...

Comment: OK been away today but will put up something tomorrow. You could probably do a 3 stage process for each combination 1) tile and reshape each array (i.e. for a, b, or c) to they are the same sized array but sequenced in different dimensions 2) & them together 3) count the bits by bitshift & 1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your triple evaluation* but you might be able to modify this to do what you want. I am assuming you will iterate through the combinations of a,b,c etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import random
import time

A = [np.random.randint(0, 2**15, random.randint(1, 5)) + 2**16 for i in range(231)]
best_score = 0
tm = time.time()
for i, a in enumerate(A):
  for j, b in enumerate(A[1:]):
    for k, c in enumerate(A[2:]):
      an, bn, cn = len(a), len(b), len(c) #some shortcuts

      a_block = np.broadcast_to(a.reshape(an, 1, 1), (an, bn, cn))
      b_block = np.broadcast_to(b.reshape(1, bn, 1), (an, bn, cn))
      c_block = np.broadcast_to(c.reshape(1, 1, cn), (an, bn, cn))

      all_and = c_block & b_block & a_block

      all_score = ((all_and & 1) + 
                   ((all_and >> 1) & 1) +
                   ((all_and >> 2) & 1) +
                   ((all_and >> 3) & 1) +
                   ((all_and >> 4) & 1) +
                   ((all_and >> 5) & 1))
      ix = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(all_score), (an, bn, cn))
      if all_score[ix] > best_score:
        print(i,j,k, ix, all_score[ix], a_block[ix], b_block[ix], c_block[ix])
        best_score = all_score[ix]
        best_abc = (i, j, k)
        best_ix = ix[:]

print(time.time() - tm)
print(best_score)
print(best_abc)
print(best_ix)
''' gives
0 0 0 (0, 2, 0) 2 95038 76894 78667
0 0 1 (0, 3, 1) 3 95038 70262 96242
0 0 2 (0, 2, 0) 4 95038 76894 96255
0 3 2 (0, 0, 0) 5 95038 96255 96255
4 3 2 (0, 0, 0) 6 96255 96255 96255
871.6093053817749
6
(4, 3, 2)
(0, 0, 0)
'''
```

EDIT * I think this code does: find the location (and value of) the maximum between a1&b1&c1, a2&b1&c1, a3&b1&c1, a1&b2&c1 etc which is possibly different from a1&b1&c1 | a2&b1&c1 | a3&b1&c1 | a1&b2&c1

EDIT2 More explicitly showing process of iterating over a pseudo dataset. a,b,c are arrays 1 to 5 long but numpy randint can't generate random numbers 60000 bits long, also I've not attempted to ensure all the numbers are unique (which would be quite easy to do) It takes about 15m on this not very powerful laptop, so that gives you a starting point for comparison.

A way to speed up the process might be to confine comparison to just two i.e. a,b to start with and keep a list of the high scorers then go through  each of those combinations &ing against all the other entries in the list to select the highest scoring three way and.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I'll need some time to check it. But can you explain the output it gives? I'm not quite sure, what it means.By the way, maybe I should remark, that the input data does not need to be those binary numbers. They are just marking the positions of the different values of a,b,c.

Comment: Here is the output of your answer: [[[1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]
 [[0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]]
(0, 0, 0)

Comment: @SvenLange Ok, so maybe it wasn't such a clear example match. I've changed a couple of numbers to give a two bit match not at 0,0,0 and added more explanation. Hopefully it's clearer now. (also renamed all_or to all_and, don't know why I called it 'or' before!)

Comment: sadly, your solution does not work, when applied to my data. the 'shape' ( an,1,1 of a.reshape(an, 1, 1)) is of length 231 and I get this error: ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32.

Comment: If you are feeding in a 231 dimensional array then that will break my code. a,b,c etc must all be one dimensional. Is there anywhere I can see the full dataset that you want to analyse?

Comment: a,b,c are one dimensional, but instead of a,b,c there are 231 for now. Also the values inside a,b,c... (e.g. 0b110000) have more likely the size of 2^60000.

Comment: Sven, You will need to use 'normal' python iteration to get your permutations of a,b,c lists. Say A = [np.array([213321,43523..., np.array([542354,234312...)] you need to do: for a in A: for b in A[1:]: for c in A[2:]... The capability of numpy to cope with number like 2^60000 I don't know!

Comment: oh man, than I'll keep searching. thanks for all your efforts! I'll post the way, I'm calculating those for now.

Comment: Sven, I can't really see how your example analysis bears much relation to your question! You code simply seems to look down each 'column' and prints that there were two occurrences of 2,5,7 you're not ``and``ing the a,b,c values at all